# Cannot convert string 'False' in attribute 'X' to object of type 'System.Boolean'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I've created an AttachedProperty wich worked just fine in test project but in larger project, where Attached Property is defined in one project and used in others I'm getting this strange error:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
    Message=Cannot convert string 'False' in attribute 'IsTextDragSource'
            to object of type 'System.Boolean'.
    Error at object 'System.Windows.HierarchicalDataTemplate' in markup file
   'ServerMonitoringModule;component/view/lists/jobbrowser/jobreportdetailsview.xaml'
   Line 147 Position 84.  Source=PresentationFramework  
   LineNumber=147   LinePosition=84  NameContext=Resources
StackTrace:
        at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition,  Uri baseUri, XamlObjectIds currentXamlObjectIds, XamlObjectIds contextXamlObjectIds, Type objectType)
        at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(ParserContext parserContext, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, String message, Exception innerException)
        at System.Windows.Markup.XamlTypeMapper.ParseProperty(Object targetObject, Type propType, String propName, Object dpOrPiOrFi, ITypeDescriptorContext typeContext, ParserContext parserContext, String value, Int16 converterTypeId)
        at System.Windows.Markup.OptimizedTemplateContent.ParseDependencyProperty(String attribValue, Int16 attributeId, Int16 converterTypeId, DependencyProperty& dp, Object& propertyValue)
        at System.Windows.Markup.OptimizedTemplateContent.LookForShareableRecord(BamlRecord bamlRecord, DependencyProperty& dp, Object& dpValue)
        at System.Windows.Markup.OptimizedTemplateContent.ReadPotentiallyShareableRecord(BamlRecord bamlRecord)
        at System.Windows.Markup.OptimizedTemplateContent.ReadRecord(BamlRecord bamlRecord) ...
```

Line where error is reported:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" dscb:TextDragHelper.IsTextDragSource="False"/>
```

And definition of property:

```
public class TextDragHelper : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTextDragSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsTextDragSource",
            typeof(bool), typeof(TextDragHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnDragSourceAdvisorChanged));
```

Did anyone encounter this before or has a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks - BoltClock - you did not answer the question but I've looked at my source and found that my setter method was:

```
public static void SetIsTextDragSource(DependencyObject source, object value)
{
    source.SetValue(IsTextDragSourceProperty, value);
}
```

And while this *somehow* worked in single project solution it did not in multi-project solution.

This fixed it:

```
public static void SetIsTextDragSource(DependencyObject source, bool value)
{
    source.SetValue(IsTextDragSourceProperty, value);
}
```